# Exterior algebra, Symmetric algebra, Divided power algebra in Characteristic $p>0$.

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, multilinear-algebra, lambda-rings

I am lacking the knowledge of multi-linear algebra while I come up with the following problems.

Suppose $k$ is a field of characteristic $p>0$. Let $E$ and $F$ be two $k$-vector spaces of dimension $r$ and $s$ respectively.

1. How to describe $\bigwedge^n(E \otimes F)$? Direct sum? Filtration?
2. I would like to have **explicit** answers to the previous question for $n =2, 3$ or even $n = 4$. If $\dim F = 1$, then $\bigwedge^n(E \otimes F) \simeq \bigwedge^n E \otimes \operatorname{T}^n F \simeq \bigwedge^n E \otimes \operatorname{Sym}^n F$. How about $\dim F =2$?
3. Do we have **natural** map $\bigwedge^n(E \otimes F) \to \bigwedge^n(E) \otimes \operatorname{Sym}^n(F)$?
4. I don't like to confuse the symmetric tensors with symmetric algebra, and alternating tensor with exterior powers. So in my definition, $\operatorname{Sym}^n(E)$ and $\bigwedge^n(E)$ are all **quotients** of $\operatorname{T}^n(E)$, while the space of symmetric tensors and alternating tensors are **subspaces** of $\operatorname{T}^n(E)$.
5. It seems that $\operatorname{Sym}(E^\vee)$ is **naturally** isomorphic to $\Gamma(E)^\vee$, where $\Gamma(E)$ is the divided power algebra. What is correct definition of $\Gamma(E)$? quotient or sub of something? What is the corresponding sub or quotient?
6. How does taking dual behave under these constructions?
7. What is the reference for such problems?

---

Problem 3 solved. Consider the natural map $\operatorname{T}^n(E \otimes F) \xrightarrow{\sim} (\operatorname{T}^n E) \otimes (\operatorname{T}^n F) \to (\bigwedge^n E) \otimes (\operatorname{Sym}^n F)$. Then we can easily see that
$\ker\big(\operatorname{T}^n (E \otimes F)\to \bigwedge^n (E \otimes F)\big)$ goes to zero under this natural map, hence it factors through $\bigwedge^n (E \otimes F)$.

3'. Is $(\bigwedge^n E) \otimes (\operatorname{Sym}^n F)$ a sub/quotient/subquotient of $\wedge^n (E\otimes F)$.

Comment: You may find some answers in Section III.2 of: [Kaan Akin, David A. Buchsbaum, Jerzy Weyman, *Schur functors and Schur complexes*](https://doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(82)90039-1). This paper works over an arbitrary ring (although only with free modules), and does distinguish between the symmetric powers and the Symmetric tensor powers (which it calls the divided powers -- or, at least, they are isomorphic to the latter).

Comment: 3. Yes: it maps $\left( e_1 \otimes f_1 \right) \wedge \left( e_2 \otimes f_2 \right) \wedge \cdots \left( e_n \otimes f_n \right)$ to $\left( e_1 \wedge e_2 \wedge \cdots e_n \right) \otimes \left( f_1 f_2 \cdots  f_n\right) $. The proof of well-definedness is not too hard: First check that it is well-defined as a map from the tensor power; then show that it factors through the exterior power because if two adjacent tensorands are equal, the output is zero (caveat: the tensorands might not be pure tensors).

Comment: 5. See Section I.4 of the above-cited paper by Akin, Buchsbaum and Weyman, but be aware that they mangle the axioms of a divided power algebra (in Condition (3), the $f $ should be an element of $R $, not of $F $; Condition (5) makes no sense in their context). I think Eisenbud's "With a view" book has a good treatment.

Comment: Now that I am back at my laptop, let me say a few more things. I myself know rather little about the subject, and learning it has been on my to-do list for years. But at least I believe I can give references. Apart from the Akin-Buchsbaum-Weyman reference, which seems nicely written but sadly teems with typos, there is a later book covering much of this subject: Giandomenico Boffi, David A. Buchsbaum, *Threading Homology Through Algebra: Selected Patterns*, Clarendon Press 2006. Also, there is the Eisenbud book I've already mentioned: ...

Comment: ... [David Eisenbud, *Commutative Algebra with a View towards Algebraic Geometry*, Springer 1995](https://archive.org/details/springer_10.1007-978-1-4612-5350-1), whose Appendix 2 I believe to be a nice source on divided power algebras. The [stacks project](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/) also has a chapter on divided power algebras; I remember learning some things out of that, and it is surprisingly readable for its position way in the back of the "book". ...

Comment: ... I also seem to recall that some of the things Akin, Buchsbaum and Weyman have done rather painfully in their work in the 1980s has later been redone in more elementary and enlightening ways by some Italians (Brini, Regonati, Teolis are the names that come to my mind; the expository [Andrea Brini, *Combinatorics, superalgebras, invariant theory and representation theory*, Séminaire Lotharingien de Combinatoire 62 (2010), Article B62d](https://eudml.org/doc/227556) seems highly relevant, but I haven't even started reading it so far.

Comment: On your new question 3': At the very least, it is a quotient, because the canonical map from the latter to the former (which I constructed in my second comment, and which you described in a more conceptual way) is surjective (just observe that any "pure" element of the codomain is in the image). Is it also a sub-Schur (bi)functor (or a $\operatorname{GL}\left(E\right) \times \operatorname{GL}\left(F\right)$-submodule)? I would suspect that the answer is "no", because it being both a sub and a quotient would feel too good to be real; arguably this is not a proof...

Comment: 6. As you probably know, for finitely-generated free $k$-modules $V$, there is a canonical isomorphism $\left(\wedge^n V\right)^\ast \to \wedge^n \left(V^\ast\right)$ that comes from the non-degenerate bilinear form $\left(\wedge^n V\right) \times \left(\wedge^n \left(V^\ast\right)\right) \to k, \  \left(v_1 \wedge v_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_n, f_1 \wedge f_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge f_n\right) \mapsto \det \left( \left( f_i\left(v_j\right) \right)_{1\leq i\leq n,\  1\leq j\leq n}\right)$. In the same situation, there is also a canonical ...

Comment: ... isomorphism $\left(D^n V\right)^\ast \to \operatorname{Sym}^n \left(V^\ast\right)$, where $D^n V$ stands for the $n$-th divided-powers module of $V$ (which is isomorphic to the $n$-th symmetric-tensors module of $V$, i.e., the $S_n$-invariant subspace of $V^{\otimes n}$).

Comment: @darijgrinberg, Thank you. Actually, I' familiar with PD algebra to some extent. But I don't know how they interplay with each other. To me, $\operatorname{Sym}$, $\bigwedge$, $\Gamma$ are all left adjoint functors, so to me they are defined by some universal properties but not concrete construction. There should be some pairings among them, and theses are what I'd like to know. It seems that most people are working over char $0$, hence it does not matter too much if they ``identify'' symmetric power as a subspace of tensor power. But this is problematic in char $p>0$.

Comment: 4. If $V$ is a finitely-generated free $k$-module, then the $n$-th "alternating-tensors" module of $V$ is canonically isomorphic to the $n$-th exterior power $\wedge^n V$. In fact, the isomorphism from $\wedge^n V$ to the $n$-th "alternating-tensors" module simply sends each $v_1 \wedge v_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_n$ to $\sum\limits_{\sigma \in S_n} \left(-1\right)^\sigma v_{\sigma\left(1\right)} \otimes v_{\sigma\left(2\right)} \otimes \cdots \otimes v_{\sigma\left(n\right)}$. But of course, no such isomorphism exists between "symmetric-tensors" and the symmetric power.

Comment: There is also a problem here in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/68004/natural-pairings-between-exterior-powers-of-a-vector-space-and-its-dual. I agree with Qiaochu Yuan that the one with $1/n!$ is more *natural* than the one without it.

Comment: @darijgrinberg -- That's a lot of comment! I think it should be an answer.